# Linux kernel stucks at "musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1" while starting

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a custom Linux board, processor is AllWinner F1Cs200s.
I have transplanted u-boot-nano-v2018.01 and Linux kernel 6.6.4. When I try to boot, the serial port output always stucks at

```
"musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1"
```

This board was made by my friend, and the firmware he transplanted could start normally. However, this problem occurred after I transplanted uboot and Linux kernel according to the instructions on a blog.  The debugging serial port of this board was customized as ttyS2. When I transplanted the Linux kernel, I only changed the corresponding part of the device tree files according to this, without changing any code in the kernel.
But I found that the output

```
"1c25800.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1c25800 (irq = 116, base_baud = 6250000) is a 16550A"
```

the serial port seems to be defined as ttyS0, I don't know if this is causing the problem, and I searched the entire folder and could not find the place where it is defined.  Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the full console output:

```
[21:52:01:786] U-Boot SPL 2018.01-05679-g013ca457fd-dirty (Dec 07 2023 - 23:47:36)␍␊
[21:52:01:795] DRAM: 64 MiB␍␊
[21:52:01:803] Trying to boot from MMC1␍␊
[21:52:01:952] ␍␊
[21:52:01:952] ␍␊
[21:52:01:952] U-Boot 2018.01-05679-g013ca457fd-dirty (Dec 07 2023 - 23:47:36 +0800)Fragaria Cake␍␊
[21:52:01:961] ␍␊
[21:52:01:961] CPU:   Allwinner F Series (SUNIV)␍␊
[21:52:01:961] Model: Fragaria Cake␍␊
[21:52:01:964] DRAM:  64 MiB␍␊
[21:52:02:489] MMC:   SUNXI SD/MMC: 0␍␊
[21:52:02:563] *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment␍␊
[21:52:02:567] ␍␊
[21:52:02:572] In:    serial@1c25800␍␊
[21:52:02:572] Out:   serial@1c25800␍␊
[21:52:02:578] Err:   serial@1c25800␍␊
[21:52:02:578] Net:   No ethernet found.␍␊
[21:52:02:587] starting USB...␍␊
[21:52:02:587] No controllers found␍␊
[21:52:02:587] Hit any key to stop autoboot:  2 <0x08><0x08><0x08> 1 <0x08><0x08><0x08> 0 ␍␊
[21:52:04:613] reading zImage␍␊
[21:52:05:056] 5111816 bytes read in 452 ms (10.8 MiB/s)␍␊
[21:52:05:083] reading suniv-f1c100s-licheepi-nano.dtb␍␊
[21:52:05:102] 6579 bytes read in 26 ms (247.1 KiB/s)␍␊
[21:52:05:115] ## Flattened Device Tree blob at 80c08000␍␊
[21:52:05:115]    Booting using the fdt blob at 0x80c08000␍␊
[21:52:05:115]    Loading Device Tree to 816fb000, end 816ff9b2 ... OK␍␊
[21:52:05:131] ␍␊
[21:52:05:131] Starting kernel ...␍␊
[21:52:05:131] ␍␊
[21:52:06:102] [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0␍␊
[21:52:06:104] [    0.000000] Linux version 6.6.4 (kuriko@Aspire) (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Linaro GCC 7.2-2017.11) 7.2.1 20171011, GNU ld (Linaro_Binutils-2017.11) 2.28.2.20170706) #5 Wed Dec  6 23:53:34 HKT 2023␍␊
[21:52:06:125] [    0.000000] CPU: ARM926EJ-S [41069265] revision 5 (ARMv5TEJ), cr=0005317f␍␊
[21:52:06:147] [    0.000000] CPU: VIVT data cache, VIVT instruction cache␍␊
[21:52:06:147] [    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Lichee Pi Nano␍␊
[21:52:06:147] [    0.000000] printk: bootconsole [earlycon0] enabled␍␊
[21:52:06:147] [    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback␍␊
[21:52:06:164] [    0.000000] Zone ranges:␍␊
[21:52:06:164] [    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x0000000083ffffff]␍␊
[21:52:06:164] [    0.000000]   HighMem  empty␍␊
[21:52:06:164] [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node␍␊
[21:52:06:164] [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges␍␊
[21:52:06:185] [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x0000000083ffffff]␍␊
[21:52:06:185] [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x0000000083ffffff]␍␊
[21:52:06:214] [    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=tty2 console=ttyS2,115200 panic=5 rootwait root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 earlyprintk rw␍␊
[21:52:06:214] [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:214] [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:237] [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 16256␍␊
[21:52:06:237] [    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off␍␊
[21:52:06:237] [    0.000000] stackdepot: allocating hash table via alloc_large_system_hash␍␊
[21:52:06:257] [    0.000000] stackdepot hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:257] [    0.000000] Memory: 50064K/65536K available (8192K kernel code, 610K rwdata, 1948K rodata, 1024K init, 1887K bss, 15472K reserved, 0K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)␍␊
[21:52:06:278] [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1␍␊
[21:52:06:304] [    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16␍␊
[21:52:06:304] [    0.000009] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns␍␊
[21:52:06:304] [    0.008000] clocksource: timer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns␍␊
[21:52:06:327] [    0.018394] Console: colour dummy device 80x30␍␊
[21:52:06:327] [    0.022910] printk: console [tty2] enabled␍␊
[21:52:06:392] [    0.028385] Calibrating delay loop... 203.16 BogoMIPS (lpj=1015808)␍␊
[21:52:06:398] [    0.103575] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok␍␊
[21:52:06:414] [    0.109246] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301␍␊
[21:52:06:414] [    0.116294] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:435] [    0.123915] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:457] [    0.151035] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100058␍␊
[21:52:06:481] [    0.164094] devtmpfs: initialized␍␊
[21:52:06:517] [    0.222023] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns␍␊
[21:52:06:525] [    0.232213] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:542] [    0.240101] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem␍␊
[21:52:06:561] [    0.262450] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family␍␊
[21:52:06:571] [    0.272265] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations␍␊
[21:52:06:611] [    0.296473] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'␍␊
[21:52:06:611] [    0.296829] cpuidle: using governor menu␍␊
[21:52:06:673] [    0.377889] SCSI subsystem initialized␍␊
[21:52:06:687] [    0.383789] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs␍␊
[21:52:06:687] [    0.390256] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub␍␊
[21:52:06:702] [    0.396445] usbcore: registered new device driver usb␍␊
[21:52:06:702] [    0.404692] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered␍␊
[21:52:06:715] [    0.409881] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>␍␊
[21:52:06:715] [    0.419607] PTP clock support registered␍␊
[21:52:06:725] [    0.427970] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.␍␊
[21:52:06:745] [    0.446455] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer␍␊
[21:52:06:930] [    0.635453] NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family␍␊
[21:52:06:935] [    0.642003] IP idents hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:961] [    0.654733] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:961] [    0.663597] Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:971] [    0.671745] TCP established hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:981] [    0.679711] TCP bind hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:06:981] [    0.686969] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 1024 bind 1024)␍␊
[21:52:06:993] [    0.694072] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:07:007] [    0.700952] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)␍␊
[21:52:07:007] [    0.710005] NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family␍␊
[21:52:07:020] [    0.723344] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.␍␊
[21:52:07:035] [    0.729538] RPC: Registered udp transport module.␍␊
[21:52:07:035] [    0.734307] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.␍␊
[21:52:07:035] [    0.739155] RPC: Registered tcp-with-tls transport module.␍␊
[21:52:07:051] [    0.744689] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.␍␊
[21:52:07:066] [    0.762038] NetWinder Floating Point Emulator V0.97 (double precision)␍␊
[21:52:07:079] [    0.777478] Initialise system trusted keyrings␍␊
[21:52:07:091] [    0.786768] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=14 bucket_order=0␍␊
[21:52:07:106] [    0.809461] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type␍␊
[21:52:07:109] [    0.814947] Key type id_resolver registered␍␊
[21:52:07:119] [    0.819412] Key type id_legacy registered␍␊
[21:52:07:702] [    1.407480] Key type asymmetric registered␍␊
[21:52:07:705] [    1.411722] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered␍␊
[21:52:07:718] [    1.418086] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)␍␊
[21:52:07:731] [    1.425621] io scheduler mq-deadline registered␍␊
[21:52:07:731] [    1.430349] io scheduler kyber registered␍␊
[21:52:08:786] [    2.491064] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 8 ports, IRQ sharing disabled␍␊
[21:52:08:868] [    2.573103] SCSI Media Changer driver v0.25 ␍␊
[21:52:08:883] [    2.587425] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage␍␊
[21:52:08:898] [    2.597084] UDC core: g_cdc: couldn't find an available UDC␍␊
[21:52:08:910] [    2.603511] i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver␍␊
[21:52:08:922] [    2.623987] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid␍␊
[21:52:08:933] [    2.629835] usbhid: USB HID core driver␍␊
[21:52:09:033] [    2.738119] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family␍␊
[21:52:09:037] [    2.744895] Key type dns_resolver registered␍␊
[21:52:09:155] [    2.860286] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates␍␊
[21:52:09:296] [    3.000669] kmemleak: Kernel memory leak detector initialized (mem pool available: 15896)␍␊
[21:52:09:414] [    3.119337] kmemleak: Automatic memory scanning thread started␍␊
[21:52:09:431] [    3.134602] gpio gpiochip0: Static allocation of GPIO base is deprecated, use dynamic allocation.␍␊
[21:52:09:535] [    3.240060] suniv-f1c100s-pinctrl 1c20800.pinctrl: initialized sunXi PIO driver␍␊
[21:52:09:550] [    3.254324] suniv-f1c100s-pinctrl 1c20800.pinctrl: supply vcc-pe not found, using dummy regulator␍␊
[21:52:09:594] [    3.299244] 1c25800.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1c25800 (irq = 116, base_baud = 6250000) is a 16550A␍␊
[21:52:09:625] [    3.330453] usb_phy_generic usb_phy_generic.0.auto: dummy supplies not allowed for exclusive requests␍␊
[21:52:09:642] [    3.344999] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: MUSB HDRC host driver␍␊
[21:52:09:647] [    3.351502] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1␍␊
```

I have tried search keyword "musb" and "hdrc" in kernel's menuconfig but nothing found at all. Since the uboot can run normally I don't think it's problem from uboot.
I have tried modified random configs that looks suspicious, but no change at all.
I really have no clue about this since the console didn't output any error. I think it might be  kernel's output is at ttyS0, different from uboot?

```
"1c25800.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1c25800 (irq = 116, base_baud = 6250000) is a 16550A"
```

But I still can't figure out why this line is refered to "ttyS0", I can't find where can I modify this.
Any help would be appreciated!